# Python `bs4.BeautifulSoup.get_text()` - get text only from the immediate level

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Suppose I have an HTML snippet and I want to `get_text` only from the immediate level:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
s = "<div><p><strong>College Type:</strong> \r\nPrivate Un-aided\r\n</p></div>"
soup = BeautifulSoup(s, 'lxml')
print soup.find('p').get_text()
```

Which prints :

```
College Type: 
Private Un-aided
```

But I want only :

```
Private Un-aided
```

which in the immediate `<p>` tag - which ignores the text from the child tag `<strong>`.

Comment: Yes its similar question:

text = True will provide only child tag data

and recursive = False will provide data which is in find('p') tag, not all child tag.

Answer (score 4):

You can search within the <p> tag for text contents, and state that you don't want to recurse into child tags:

```
>>> print soup.find('p').find(text=True, recursive=False)

Private Un-aided
```